# Thread in C++ in MacOS X

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, std

I'm trying to run some code using threads in standard C++ (installed with XCode) in MacOS X Mavericks. But I'm getting some errors. Here's a minimal working example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void run (int x) {
    std::cout<<".";
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::thread t(run);
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
minimal.cpp:10:17: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
std::thread t(run,0);
            ^ ~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/thread:372:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but 2 arguments
  were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/thread:261:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
thread(const thread&);
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/thread:268:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(0) {}
^
1 error generated.
```

I've been able to track the problem to my compiler defining `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_VARIADICS`, which is defined because of

```
#if !(__has_feature(cxx_variadic_templates))
#define _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_VARIADICS
#endif
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What command line arguments are you passing to clang?

Comment: I'm compiling with g++, I only do `g++ minimal.cpp`. `clang++ minimal.cpp` also fails.

Comment: add --std=c++11 and see if it helps

Comment: It does help in the compiling, but running gives me
`libc++abi.dylib: terminating ` `.Abort trap: 6`

Comment: that's probably a different issue.  Try running it through gdb and see where it breaks.

Comment: @user3267581 try adding `t.join();` at the end of main

Comment: Yep, that did it. I just needed to add a `t.join()`. Thank you very much. I'd like to give you an accepted answer, but as this is a comment... Let me know if I should answer myself. (So if this happens to anyone else they will know)

Comment: @user3267581 just answer yourself

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to `pwny` and `PeterT`, I figured out the error.

I just needed to compile with `clang++ -std=c++11 minimal.cpp` and it worked like a charm.
I also needed a `t.join()` at the end to prevent an execution error to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the clang tip. The default g++ doesn't work.

Comment: How can we use `g++` in this case? I know `clang++ -std=c++11` works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

i'm getting different std::thread behaviour running same app. on xcode or instruments (profiling), on xcode the single thread/multithread ratio is 0.6 and in instruments is 3.7 using a 4 thread array,

how is this possible?

```
 Xcode run:

st...ok - lap: 4875 ms
st/8...ok - lap: 1205 ms
mt...ok - lap: 8330 ms
st/mt ratio:**0.6**

Instruments run:

st...ok - lap: 2182 ms
st/8...ok - lap: 545 ms
mt...ok - lap: 596 ms
st/mt ratio:**3.7**
```