# multithreading c++ passing arguments to a function

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have been trying to pass arguments to a thread function but haven't been able to. I tried reading about it ([Passing multiple arguments to a threaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486987/passing-multiple-arguments-to-a-threaded-function)) but I still couldn't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void func(int t)
{
    cout << t << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(func,4);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I ran it in the command line (I use zsh incase that matters) by doing this:

```
g++ test.cpp
./a.out
```

but I got these errors:

```
thread_test.cpp:14:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::thread'
thread t1(func,4);
       ^  ~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:379:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but
  2 arguments were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:268:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
thread(const thread&);
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:275:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(0) {}
^
1 error generated.
```

in case this is important I am using a mac with OSX 10.11.4

Also, to see what versions of c++ I was compiling with I ran this command and got this out put:

```
g++ --version
```

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Can't reproduce : http://ideone.com/BFRbzc . What compiler are you using?

Comment: [Works with normal clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f95035aaa16f9fc4), so Apple probably broke something again. Good testcase though.

Comment: [Possible duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031640/thread-in-c-in-macos-x) Make sure you're compiling with `--std=c++11` (or higher).

Comment: I've edited the question so you should now know the compiler I am using but I don't know how I would find out if I were compiling with    --std=c++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `-std=c++11` and it will work; see my transcript below. (Running on OS X.)

```
nathanst% g++ t.cpp 
t.cpp:13:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::thread'
    thread t1(func,4);
           ^  ~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:379:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but 2 arguments were
      provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:268:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
    thread(const thread&);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:275:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
    thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(0) {}
    ^
1 error generated.
nathanst% g++ -std=c++11 t.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks! Still one question though, what is -std=c++11 and why do I need it? If it's because I am not using c++11 then how can I update to c++11?

Comment: The compiler you are using knows about the new C++11 functionality, but has it turned off by default. -std=c++11 tells the compiler to turn on that functionality. At some point a newer version will have it turned on by default and you will no longer need that switch.